# Simple password field on page or video

Tags: html, passwords

I’m building a really basic website for a surprise birthday thing for my brother and sister’s 30th. It’s basically a real world treasure hunt. At some point they’ll get the web address for my website, and on that website will be a video giving them a clue.

Now, I also want them to have a password (which they’ll have found earlier) that will allow them access to the website OR the video. Either that the page containing the video is password protected or the video itself is password protected.

I have *very* basic knowledge of HTML, I found a HTML code for a password field that when correct would open a new page, but that doesn’t seem to work.. from reading other blogs I’m thinking it might not be as simple as one HTML code?

Can someone please help? I don’t need any username/login fields, just a password field - and either a password to play a video or a password to take them to a new page which contains the video...

I’m also more than happy to just use a website builder if anyone knows of a decent one that will easily allow me to do this...

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ultra-basic example may help:

```js
const goodPassword = 'thisisthepassword';
document.forms.pwd.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (e.target.elements[0].value !== goodPassword) {
    e.target.elements[0].value = '';
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- Put your website link as the form action attribute value -->
<form name="pwd" method="GET" action="[ Your video page URL ]">
  <label for="q">Password:
    <input type="password" name="q" />
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Okay so I’ve pasted this in exactly as it is, just amending the action link - it displays EXACTLY as I wanted it to look (thank you!) but when I put in the password it just shows up as incorrect.. so forgive me for being stupid but just so I can check, as I’ve pasted it exactly from yours, the password is *thisisthepassword* and I keep all the spaces and brackets as you’ve included them (I.e. around the URL?)

Comment: You should remove the brackets and the spaces. Just the url surrounded by double quotes.